# laravel eloquent collection orderby firstly null then filed value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have `$items` with this `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance. The result of `dd($items->toArray())` is

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "start_date" => "Jan 1997"
    "end_date" => "Jan 2000"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "start_date" => "Jan 2000"
    "end_date" => "Jan 2003"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "start_date" => "Jan 2007"
    "end_date" => ""
  ]
]
```

I want to order by end_date. Firstly empty values than desc like this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "start_date" => "Jan 2007"
    "end_date" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "start_date" => "Jan 2000"
    "end_date" => "Jan 2003"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "start_date" => "Jan 1997"
    "end_date" => "Jan 2000"
  ]
]
```

How can do it in correct way.
I try `$items->sortByDesc('end_date')` but that case empty values is the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement your own sort function as mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sort)

you can do something like

```
$items = $items->sort(function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->end_date == '') { return -1; } // this will set the empty value always before the other
    // pseudo code
    $firstDate = \Carbon::parse($a->end_date);
    $secondDate = \Carbon::parse($b->end_date);
    if ($firstDate->lessThan($secondDate)) { return - 1; }
    if ($firstDate->equalTo($secondDate)) { return 0; }
    return 1;
});
```